# Javascript appending; What is considered best practice?

Tags: javascript, append

Can anyone explain what is considered the best practice in appending in javascript?

```
var element = document.createElement('p');
element.innerHTML = 'This is appended' ;
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.appendChild(element);
```

or

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.innerHTML = '<p>This is appended</p>';
```

I see a lot of people doing it like this in jQuery:

```
$('#div').append('<p>This is appended</p>');
```

But i've always done it like this:

```
var element = document.createElement('p');
element.innerHTML = 'This is appended' ;
$('#div').append(element);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: All those solutions are good. If I'm using jQuery, My approach would be to take #3 as I like to keep my code short and I dislike #4 as it mixes vanilla javascript with jQuery, but all in all, any of those solutions can be used.

Comment: don't use `.innerHTML` if you are using jQuery. Anything that possibly removes elements must go through jQuery so that it won't leak memory.

Comment: @Esailija is absolutely right. For that matter, don't use other DOM manipulation libraries alongside jQuery, as the same leaks can occur.

Answer (score 5):

if you're using jQuery, absolutely nothing wrong with:

`$('#div').append('<p>This is appended</p>');`

Its less code and less steps.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, when you're working with a DOM, treat it like a DOM instead of a string.

In other words, don't use *markup* to create elements or text nodes. Use DOM creation methods.

```
document.getElementById('div')
        .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode('This is appended'));
```

---

Microsoft's `.innerHTML` invention can be tempting, and perhaps useful in a pinch, but I usually avoid it.

You can reduce the verbosity of the methods above with helpers.

Comment: Agreed. However, as it turns out, string manipulation is always almost faster than DOM manipulation. Just not as "clean" I suppose.

Comment: @hackNightly: I think that's changing in modern browsers. I'm pretty sure I saw some performance comparison that suggested the opposite, though I may be remembering incorrectly. Probably depends to some degree on the complexity of the markup being parsed.

Comment: ...one more consideration is that if you're using jQuery, performance is probably not a major concern in the first place. jQuery's abstraction usually comes with a pretty good hit.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the answers, its always nice to hear different opinions!

Answer (score 2):

I typically build an element using jQuery.

```
var paragraph = $("<p />", {
  className : "someClass",
  text : "this is appended"
})


div.append(paragraph)
```

I believe that this approach is preferred to directly injecting HTML because it's less intrusive on the DOM.

Comment: you can just `text: "This is appended"` as a property of the object

Comment: FYI, some browsers will choke on `class:` as a non-quoted property name. Either wrap it in quotes, or use `className:`.